# Debugging node.js applications with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging

I am trying to follow the instructions on how to [debug node.js applications](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger) with Eclipse. But the breakpoints don't get enabled as shown in the screenshot below. Can anyone point me to the solution.

[image]

Comment: Is this your own screenshot, or a screenshot from the instruction site?

Comment: My screenshot. As you can see there is a line through the circle which says that the breakpoint is not enabled. That is my problem.

Comment: diagonal line through breakpoint: all breakpoints have been disabled (button skip all breakpoints in breakpoint view)

Comment: Oh man.. How could I miss that. Thanks a lot for your help though. Otherwise I would have spent a lot of time without seeing that. Can you put that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Happy to have saved you some hours :)  I have added my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your breakpoints are disabled.  Enable it by uncheck skip all breakpoints in breakpoint view.

Answer (score 0):

Heh, you're working with the same tick function that they used in the tutorial I read. Probably the same tutorial.

Another interesting thing that I found when setting up Eclipse like this is that to be able to debug a real app you have to delay it from running, like the ticker does, but a little more intelligently of course. Here's how I'm doing it so far .. (hopefully this will help as well):

```
function __myapp_start() {
    console.log('Running app ...');
    // run your app here ...
};

if (process.argv[2] === '-dbg') { // `node --debug myapp.js -dbg`  wait for the debugger to connect. 
    function __myapp_pause() {
        var paused = new Date().getTime();
        debugger; // will return immediately if the debugger is not connected yet
        var started = new Date().getTime();
        if (started - paused < 500) { // if we returned relatively quickly, assume we're not connected and loop
            setTimeout(__myapp_pause, 500);
        } else { // the debugger actually paused and took time to return; we're connected. run.
            __myapp_start();
        }
    }

    __myapp_pause(); // attempt to pause the debugger until it actually does pause, then continue
} else { // normal production path
    __myapp_start();
}
```